# tensor product of sheaves is not a sheaf

Tags: differential-topology, sheaf-theory

I was looking for an example of two sheaves that satisfy the gluing and uniqueness axioms but whose tensor product is a presheaf, but not a sheaf (doesn't satisfy uniqueness, for example).

Thank you very much.

Comment: So to clarify, by "sheaf" you mean a sheaf of abelian groups, and by "tensor product" you mean the pointwise tensor product of presheaves of abelian groups?

Comment: By Sheaf I mean a presheaf of $A$-Modules with $A$ a principal ideal domain that satisfies the gluing and uniqueness condition. So it's slightly more specific.

Comment: And yes, by tensor product I mean: the pointwise tensor product of the associated $A$ modules.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the sheaves $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{G}=\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ of locally constant functions with values in $\mathbb{Z}$. Almost by definition : $\mathcal{F}(U)=\mathbb{Z}^{\pi_0(U)}$.

Now consider an open subset $U$ with two connected components. You have $$\mathcal{F}(U)\otimes\mathcal{G}(U)=\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus 2}\otimes\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus 2}=\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus 4}.$$

However $\mathcal{P}:V\mapsto\mathcal{F}(V)\otimes\mathcal{G}(V)$ is not a sheaf (in fact its associated sheaf is again $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$). To see this, consider the open covering of $U$ by its two components $U_1$ and $U_2$. If $\mathcal{P}$ was a sheaf, we would have the equality $\mathcal{P}(U)=\mathcal{P}(U_1)\oplus\mathcal{P}(U_2)$. But it doesn't hold.

Comment: YAY THANKS! you man

Comment: "we would have the equality P(U)=P(U1)⊕P(U2)P(U)=P(U1)⊕P(U2)." Why is that? Sheafs separate different connected components but presheafs do not?

Comment: @WernerGermánBusch The constant presheaf, or the tensor presheaf above, does not separate connected components. In fact, why should they ? There is no reason for this in the definition of presheaf. However sheaves satisfies the equality $F(U)=F(U_1)\oplus F(U_2)$ if $U_1$ and $U_2$ are the connected components of $U$. This follows immediately from the sheaf condition with the covering of $U$ by $U_1$ and $U_2$.

Comment: "The constant presheaf, or the tensor presheaf above, does not separate connected components. In fact, why should they ?"

That's what I said.... lol

Comment: Why it doesn't hold? $F(U_1)=\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z^{\oplus 2}}$, isn't it?

Comment: @jpatrick No $\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$, the map $a\otimes b\rightarrow ab$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I deleted my last question, because it's trivial and this isomorphism is also. Sorry for stupid questions...